# Is it possible to make Visual Studio throw a build error on implicit casts of DateTime to DateTimeOffset?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, datetimeoffset

Is it possible to make Visual Studio throw a build error on implicit casts of DateTime to DateTimeOffset?

E.g.

```
var testDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
var checkDate = CastTest(testDate); // Make this throw exception at compile time
```

with function

```
public static DateTimeOffset CastTest(DateTimeOffset date)
{
    return date;
}
```

The reason I want this is because the implicit cast assumes local system offset and I **never** want implicit local offset in this application.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/32954#issuecomment-660499633 - I found this by searching Google. I don't know if it can be extended to a cause an error without treating all warnings as errors though (I've never used that analyzer package though).

Comment: In many cases if not all, severity is configurable (when the warning/suggestion shows up use the tooltip menu to configure).